# Bootstrap navbar dropdown login

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, navbar, dropdown, bootstrap-4

I want to create login and registration dropdown form. I read multiple topics on this website and nothing seemed to work for me.

Here is how it currently looks:

[image: Current look]

I want the form to be just above Login link. I noticed that when I click on white space around the username and password input fields, the form disappears and I have to bring it up again by clicking on Login. How do I fix that?

Here is my code for navbar:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark">
<a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><img src="http://shrani.si/f/46/2Q/2Ps2wfOq/camera.png"></a>
<button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
<span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
</button>
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
        <li class="nav-item active">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Photo Master</span></a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Upload Your Own</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Contact</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-right">
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="http://example.com" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
            Login
            </a>
            <div class="dropdown-menu" style="padding: 15px; padding-bottom: 10px;">
                <form class="form-horizontal" method="post" accept-charset="UTF-8">
                    <input class="form-control login" type="text" name="username" placeholder="Username.." /><br>
                    <input class="form-control login" type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password.."/><br>
                    <input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" name="submit" value="Login" />
                </form>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="http://example.com" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
            Register
            </a>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
        <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="text" placeholder="Search..." aria-label="Search">
        <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
    </form>
</div>
```

And a short CSS code to style it:

```
.login {
    margin-bottom:5px;
}
.dropdown-menu {
    width: 300px !important;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The nav item needs the `dropdown` class..

https://www.codeply.com/go/o7Ys06Z3c9

```
        <li class="nav-item dropdown">
            <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="http://example.com" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
            Login
            </a>
            <div class="dropdown-menu" style="padding: 15px; padding-bottom: 10px;">
                <form class="form-horizontal" method="post" accept-charset="UTF-8">
                    <input class="form-control login" type="text" name="username" placeholder="Username.."><br>
                    <input class="form-control login" type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password.."><br>
                    <input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" name="submit" value="Login">
                </form>
            </div>
        </li>
```

Comment: Thank you, it works! :) How can I keep the form opened after I click the button?